# Matching integer arrays using regular expressions engine

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is it possible to match **integer arrays** using a regular expressions engine in .NET.
For example:

```
var a = new short[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var r = new NumericRegex("^/1/2.{2}(/5|/10)/6$");
var match = r.Match(a);
```

Conceptually there is no difference between ints and chars, but how to implement it?

**UPD:**

One of the possible solutions is to convert ints to unicode chars. But how to exclude regex special characters or encode them?

Comment: So, you want to get new array, values of which satisfies regex?

Comment: Why not converting the int array to string first, using LINQ? and then apply your Regex. Or why dont you upgrade your int array to a List<int> and then call .Where()?

Comment: You want to do pattern matching on the `int[]` instead of strings, right?

Comment: Are you planning to use the full range of integers, or a limited range of, say, 16-bit integers would work?

Comment: I've been on the lookout, but haven't found anything.  Had to write my own with iterators.  A related question for the JVM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108919/matching-a-stream-for-certain-conditions

Comment: @AdrianSalazar How to do this exactly?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In my case 16-bit integers works too.

Comment: @alexey excluding regex special characters is simple if you build the regular expression by hand. As their set is finite and they are all known, you could just escape them as usual. You don't make your regexes at run-time, do you?

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about **shorts**, this modification of previous answer seems to work just fine:

```
var a = new short[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 33, 32, 43, 34 };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char i in a) { sb = sb.Append(i); }
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Match(sb.ToString(), "\u0005\u0021\u0020\\u002B\u0022").Value);
```

Note `char i in a` instead of `var i in a`.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited**

It is not possible to directly match int array with Regex.

According to documentation  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) Match method takes paremeter as string.

You have to convert int array to string first. 
You can convert int array to string by following

```
 var a = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var i in a)
        {
            sb = sb.Append(i);
        }
  var result=sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to find a library that would help.

Comment: May be OP trying to find a library. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: How would you parse the resulting string "123456"? "123" and "456"? or "12", "34" and "56" ? ;)